# Is it true that $nx_n>(n+1)x_{n+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

Suppose that $\{x_n:n\ge1\}$ is a positive real sequence such that $x_n>x_{n+1}$ for each $n\ge1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n<\infty$. It follows that $nx_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

> Is it true that $nx_n>(n+1)x_{n+1}$ for large values of $n$?

It is straightforward to construct an example where this is the case (for instance, $x_n=n^{-2}$). Also, it does not necessarily hold for each $n$ (take, for example, $x_n=0.99^n$). I am struggling to construct a counterexample, but I nonetheless think that the answer is negative. Is it possible to construct an example, where the inequality does not hold for infinitely many values of $n$?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Careful. You need more than that to conclude that $n x_n \to 0$. For example, if you let $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ whenever $n$ is a perfect square, and $0$ otherwise, then summing $x_n$ produces $\pi^2 / 6$, but $n x_n$ is not convergent, oscillating between $1$ and $0$. You probably need a monotone sequence too.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the comment! I assume that the sequence is positive and strictly monotone. Do I still need to more to conclude that $nx_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Nope, monotone is enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this one?

$$\displaystyle x_n=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{n^2}&n\in 2\mathbb N\\ \frac{1}{n(n+1)}& n\in 2\mathbb N+1\end{cases} \\$$

Comment: Thanks! In this example, we either have that $nx_n=(n+1)x_{n+1}$ or $nx_n>(n+1)x_{n+1}$ depending on the parity of $n$, right?

Comment: Right, I constructed it that way to make it simpler, but it should be straightforward to modify to get strict inequality instead of equality.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible that the inequality holds only for finitely many $n$. Assume that, for all $n\geq N$,

$$nx_n \leq (n+1)x_{n+1}.$$

Then, as the sequence $a_n=nx_n$ is increasing along $n\geq N$, we have that

$$Nx_N \leq nx_n$$

for all $n\geq N$. So

$$\frac{Nx_N}{n} \leq x_n,$$

so $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} x_n$ diverges by the comparison test.

For an example where both the inequality is false for infinitely many values of $n$ (and holds for infinitely many values of $n$), see Michael Biro's answer.

Comment: good.....................

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Thanks for noting - I've edited my answer to reference Michael Biro's; his should satisfy all your conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1)! That's a good observation. Actually, $nx_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ and $nx_n$ is eventually going to be smaller than $Nx_N$ so we get a contradiction.